# Installing pyqtgraph on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pyqtgraph

What does this mean in the pyqtgraph installation description on http://www.pyqtgraph.org/: "All that is needed is for the pyqtgraph folder to be placed someplace importable."

So I donwloaded the .deb file for Ubuntu and now where should I put it?

I tried to move the .deb file into `/urs/lib/python2.7` but i still get from python: "ImportError: No module named pyqtgraph"

The same if I extract the .deb file and then I move to the same location the folder I got from the extraction.

I get this if I print sys.path from python:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client
```

What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the terminal, you have to install the `.deb` package by first using `cd` to go to where the `.deb` package is located (probably in `~/Downloads`) and then running the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i python-pyqtgraph_0.9.10-1_all.deb
```

Answer (score 6):

For installing pyqtgraph, I would use pip package manager instead.

Just run in the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install pyqtgraph
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another method: 
http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/installation.html references adding

`deb http://luke.campagnola.me/debian dev/` to your /etc/apt/sources.list file.

Afterward: 
`sudo apt-get update` and then 
`sudo apt-get install python-pyqtgraph`.

While apt-get is just a front-end for dpkg, apt-get supposedly checks dependencies.  I haven't quite figured out the mechanism by which apt-get checks those dependencies, so with this being a non-standard repo link I'm not sure how well they would be checked, it gave me a warmer fuzzy to use apt-get, whether it was warranted or not.  Of course lots of evidence out there for pros and cons of using pip as @Federico suggests as well.